# NHibernate object references an unsaved transient instance save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to save a complex object which has many referenced elements inside and it works perfectly most of the time.
However in some cases we are getting the below exception,

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: Namespace.Core.Client.ClientDetails, Entity: Namespace.Core.Client.ClientDetails

The problem is, there are around 12 ClientDetails elements inside my complex object which we are trying to save.Is there a way to identify which object instance caused this issue?
through NHibernate logging or some other way?
My code sample used for save as below,

```
_repository.Save<SuperParent>(obj);
_repository.Flush();
```

Please note when i set the Nhibernate show_sql to true i am able to see all the queries properly generated, but when the flush is called, the exception is thrown.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Just a hint. Each object is by NHibernate distinguished if it is new/transient to be INSERTED or existing to be UPDATED. In case of `int` ID, it is: `ID > 0` object is exsiting, `ID == 0` object is new. Try to check, before the Flush, which object does not have the ID generated... this will be the suspected. Having this, you can find the Property collection to which it belongs to and mark it with *cascade* attribute ... NHibernate will then save all the stuff for you

Comment: Look into the inner exception if present. Usually NHibernate throws the exception for the object which did not get saved (where ID is 0). So the exception/inner exception should give you enough detail to figure it out.

Comment: Hi Radim, yes i tried to collect all generated queries. But it happens in 2 steps. 1. When _repository.Save(obj) is called NHibernate generates all the required INSERT sql queries without the FK references. 2. When _repository.Flush() is called, NHibernate generates the UPDATE queries to update all the FK references between all objects and it is not finding there is one less UPDATE for 'ClientDetails' element and throws this exception.Please correct me if my understanding is wrong and advice.

Comment: Hi MichaC, there is no inner exception details, it gives only till the entity name and there is no object id or other value through which we can identify the exact object instance causing the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 16):

The exception means that there is an unsaved instance of `ClientDetails` referenced by this object. You have to either save it manually before saving the parent

```
session.Save(Parent.SomeDetail);
```

or set `Cascade.SaveOrUpdate` on the reference-mappings in the parent mapping.

Comment: Hi, Finally we found the issue, there was a technical reference of an object linked to an object in the parent which i am trying to save is in a different object tree, means this cliendetails reference is not part of the object tree but a particular instance is referring to this.And when i correct this object i am able to save it successfully.Thanks for all your freedback

Comment: @Firo could you please elaborate (with a code snippet if possible) how to change the fluent reference mappings in the parent mapping ?

Comment: `References(x => x.DetailProperty).Cascade.All();`

Answer (score 4):

If you read carefully:

> ...he transient instance before flushing or **set cascade action** for the property to something that would make it autosave

So, maybe you can add Cascade to the Reference, like this:

```
References(x => x.ClientDetails).Cascade.All().Column("ClientDetailsId")
                  .Not.Nullable();  //Or nullable, this depends on your schedule
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your mapping to **cascade** all **changes**.If you have a Client Class that have many ClientDetails , your xml mapping would be like this

In Client.hbm.xml file you should have :

```
<set name = "ClientDetails" table = "`ClientDetail`" cascade = "all-delete-orphan" inverse="true"> 
         <key column = "ClientId"/> 
         <one-to-many class = "ClientDetail"/> 
</set>
```

In ClientDetail.hbm.xml file you should have :

```
<many-to-one name = "Client" class = "Client" column = "ClientId " />
```

Answer (score 1):

This error also happens when you have a complex object that includes children that are reference data (think ClientType class).
If the child has a version element in it's mapping file that maps to an int column in your database, the version number for an existing row should never be set to 0.  Nhibernate interprets this as an object to be inserted on a cascade update and will fail as it's attempting to insert a row that already exists.